# APPCRASH with mshtml.dll

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

I recently started getting APPCRASH crash errors. My situation is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/352876/appcrash-and-possible-malware) (in that a .dll file causes Windows Desktop Gadgets to crash), but the solution of scanning with MalwareBytes did not work for me. All of them seem to be caused by mshtml.dll. The error reports:

Windows Desktop Gadgets

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:    sidebar.exe
>
> Application Version: 6.1.7601.17514
>
> Application Timestamp:   4ce7a1c7
>
> Fault Module Name:   mshtml.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:    10.0.9200.16576
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:  515e3be5
>
> Exception Code:  c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:    0000000000023dfb
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>
> Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    935c
>
> Additional Information 2:    935cdd6cb1f65a918e65359ef3d3c0e3
>
> Additional Information 3:    5913
>
> Additional Information 4:    591332b3b68f04691b8a7657d837a9b2

.NET Reflector 8.1.035

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:    Reflector.exe
>
> Application Version: 8.1.0.35
>
> Application Timestamp:   51815f6a
>
> Fault Module Name:   mshtml.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:    10.0.9200.16576
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:  515e3be5
>
> Exception Code:  c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:    0000000000023dfb
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>
> Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    ab18
>
> Additional Information 2:    ab18c9216818a6ada82d31e78f14eb55
>
> Additional Information 3:    78c8
>
> Additional Information 4:    78c8fdc3edce8561db582be3f30bddc2

Autodesk 3ds Max 2012

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>
> Application Name:    LMU.exe
>
> Application Version: 4.0.35.0
>
> Application Timestamp:   4d06d384
>
> Fault Module Name:   mshtml.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:    10.0.9200.16576
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:  515e3be5
>
> Exception Code:  c0000005
>
> Exception Offset:    0000000000023dfb
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>
> Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    a789
>
> Additional Information 2:    a789803427aca2d2e0215a378699ade9
>
> Additional Information 3:    80e2
>
> Additional Information 4:    80e2f41d0a05c9bbb2e66b625fc416cb

As you can see, all of the information regarding mshtml.dll is the same. This has led me to believe that there is something wrong with my copy of the dll file, but webpages load perfectly file with all browsers. The only commonality between these crashes is that a program is trying to connect to the internet (Desktop Gadgets to get news, 3ds Max and Reflector to check registration). However, most other applications work perfectly fine when connecting to the internet.

Do I have a virus? Malware? Neither MalwareBytes nor Microsoft Security Essentials Prerelease detect anything in a full scan, and most Googling I've done details not being able to load pages in Internet Explorer. I'm at a loss on how to fix this.

Comment: Did you try resetting IE?

Comment: Like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737)? When I do that, I get an 'X' next to "Resetting user customizations"

Comment: I assume you ran the FixIt? Did you try from Internet Options / Advanced tab?

Comment: Just did: Everything reset correctly and I restarted my computer (as it said I had to for changes to take effect). Things still crash, unfortunately.

Comment: remove IE10 and look if you also get the issues with IE9.